# JIT compiler and inner loop

Tags: java, performance, jit

Why is the JIT-compiler not working for the following code?

*And every individual loop seem to take too long time*

(see my other post about executing time. [Speed of simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848617/speed-of-simple-loop/18849640?noredirect=1#18849640)

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {  
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        float f;

        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
            f = i * 0.0001F;
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long timeToCallNanoTime = System.nanoTime() - end;
        long time = Math.max(0, end - start - timeToCallNanoTime);
        System.out.println("time: " + time + " ns.");
    }

}
```

RESULT:

```
 time: 6639317628 ns.
 time: 6630196045 ns.
 time: 6632583856 ns.
 time: 6617596798 ns.
 time: 6605243858 ns.
 time: 6609097755 ns.
 time: 6627151876 ns.
 time: 6623427381 ns.
 time: 6632506712 ns.
 time: 6615870257 ns.
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in as you can see in my answer to your previous question.

Most likely you are using the client JVM which comes with 32-bit Windows. The client JVM doesn't optimise the code as much to minimise startup time.  I suggest you use the 64-bit JVM which uses the `-server` JVM by default and it will optimise the code more aggressively.

BTW I was using Java 7 update 40.  If you have a really old version of Java, it might not optimise the loop away.

Comment: Yes, I also get time: 2827136 ns.
time: 4592281 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.
time: 0 ns.